When does a Lie algebra's outer automorphism group 'inherit' a representation?
EDIT: So, my question I believe can be broken down to: for a Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and an outer automorphism on $\mathfrak{g}$ named $\hat{O}$: if I have a representation $\rho$, the question is what is the relationship between $\rho(\mathfrak{g})$ and $\rho(\hat{O}(\mathfrak{g}))$? For the fundamental rep's of $SU(3)$, the relationship is conjugation, for the adjoint, its linear as below, and for the spinor and vector reps of $SO(8)$ there is no linear or anti-linear map between those representations.
The question is: Why? Is there a generic way to relate automorphisms of the algebra, to the outer automorphisms of the $GL(n,\mathbb{R})\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ etc.? To see why for some groups the automorphism may be 'manifested' at a representation theoretic level, and for some it remains purely an 'adjoint' phenomenon.

Original Question:
In the following I am considering finite dimensional representations of semi-simple Lie algebras over fields of characteristic $0$.
Examples should illuminate what I am getting at. Consider $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ in the standard basis (structure constants agreeing with the commutation relations of the mathematicians Gell-Mann matrices): The algebra has a (representation independent) automorphism given by the reflection:
$$\lambda_1 \mapsto -\lambda_1, \quad \lambda_3 \mapsto -\lambda_3$$
$$\lambda_4 \mapsto -\lambda_4, \quad\lambda_6 \mapsto -\lambda_6, \quad\lambda_8 \mapsto -\lambda_8$$
What is interesting to me is that this automorphism manifests differently in different representations. For the defining $(1,0)$ representation, the automorphism manifests as complex conjugation - an outer automorphism of the underlying field. Contrast this with the (real) adjoint representation, where this automorphism is achieved of course by an inner automorphism: (multiplicative) conjugation by the matrix $\operatorname{diag}\{-1,+1,-1,-1,+1,-1,+1,-1\}$.
In both cases here the automorphism was achieved not at the level of the Lie algebra itself, but 'internal' to the particular representation (using the adjoint rep is cheating a little, but its still true when considering the action as merely $8\times8$ matrices$^\mathbf{1}$) i.e. For each representation, there appears to be a representation of the corresponding Dynkin diagrams automorphism. However this 'representation' of the algebra's automorphism group does not appear to exist for all semi-simple algebra's representations.
When exploring the triality of $\mathfrak{so}(8)$ I was surprised to discover it is seemingly impossible to find a 'representation' of the action of any of it's outer automorphisms in the three $\mathbf{8}$ representations.
So I'm left wondering, given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, with outer automorphism group $Out(\mathfrak{g})$, and a representation $\rho$, when does "$\rho(Out(\mathfrak{g}))$" exist?
It would seem (at least for real Lie algebras) that they always are somewhat obviously realizable in the adjoint representation, but how else could I know whether or not it is possible in some particular representation without brute forcing it?

Footnote $\mathbf{1.}$ I wasn't sure where to put this thought/query: I imagine that since every finite dimensional representation can be found in some tensor product of $(1,0)$ with itself, and the automorphism acts on this rep by complex conjugation, this is why we say complex conjugation acts on the weight lattice, when really it is the representation independent automorphism which is acting upon the weight lattice. But this does not generalize to $\mathfrak{so}(8)$, where the outer automorphisms certainly exist, but there is not $8$-dimensional representation of these automorphisms for us to take as 'primitive' in some sense.

I'm not familiar enough with the details to offer a complete answer, but in general when you pull back a representation along an outer automorphism you get a non-isomorphic representation. This happens in the triality example where the three $8$-dimensional representations are permuted. So the outer automorphism does not act on any of these. Sometimes you get an isomorphic representation and then you can choose an isomorphism to define an "equivariant structure." So in the triality example you could potentially act on the sum of the three $8$-dimensional representations.

You raise a good point about the imprecise language I'm using. If an automorphism leaves the representation the same, then the "representation" of the automorphism makes at least some sense. But if the automorphism changes my representation it seems at least misleading to call it "$\rho(O)$" since it is a map taking me from one representation to another, I'm not staying in $\rho$. You're right that it is probably easier to at least begin by classifying equivariant structures/intertwiners of reducible representations which are sums of the relevant representations.
